# How can I manage what data is synced to a Meteor client's cache?

Tags: meteor

I modified the leaderboard example to use two collections:

```
Players = new Meteor.Collection("players");
Tasks = new Meteor.Collection("tasks");
```

The Players collection has the 6 documents defined in the example.

```
> db.players.count()
6
```

The Tasks collection has 48,000 documents.

```
> db.tasks.count()
48000
```

As soon as I open the browser, Node jumps to 100% CPU and the client can't see any of the tasks records.

```
Players.find().count()
6
Tasks.find().count()
0
```

I tried defining query criteria but that only works on the server and doesn't help on the client.

```
Players.find({name:"Claude Shannon"}).count();
1
Tasks.find({tid:"t36254"}).count();
0
```

I'm guessing that 48,000 documents is too much to sync.  That's causing Node to peg at 100% CPU and the client to throw errors like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4dpX.png.

How do I prevent syncing everything and only retrieve specific documents from the collection?

Comment: Part of the answer appears to be to disable the autopublish function.  Autopublish  makes simple examples "just work" with a handful of documents, but it doesn't do well with more data. In the project directory, use 'meteor remove autopublish'. Then write your own publish and subscribe functions.

Answer (score 18):

The autopublish of Meteor, which publishes all of your collections to the client, is very impressive and makes things work fast, but it's kind of like Rails scaffolding functionality - not very useful for real apps - it's for learning and prototyping.

By default, Meteor automatically publishes every document in your collection to each connected client. To turn this behavior off, remove the package:

$ meteor remove autopublish

Then, learn to use the manual publish and subscribe functions, which offers you the control you need: http://docs.meteor.com/#publishandsubscribe

Comment: also remove insecure: meteor remove insecure

Comment: @radtek: it's critical that we remove the `insecure` package for security but one should note that removing it doesn't answer the original question at all.

Comment: @Clawsy My comment is in addition to the current answer, not a full answer.